# Authenticating against a webapi using azure b2c from an spa (angular and adal.js)

Tags: angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api2, adal

I'm trying to authenticate my SPA (angular.js and adal.js (similar to the 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi example)

My AD is a azure b2c preview tenant.

I can successfully log in to my webapi from my Website, but not from the JS SPA via angular.

My Setup:
Webapi and Website share the same clientid (does only seem to work this way)
The SPA has its own clientid, because otherwise i get "api version not supported" errors when trying to log in.
I have enabled oauth2AllowImplicitFlow for all applications, granted application permissions from the spa to the webapi. 
Cors is enabled on the Webapi and the SPA.

I even seem to be able to get a token after completing the login, but when i try to call my api, i get an access denied for this request.

Is this supposed to work this way? I could not find an example of how to use b2c together with a spa and the api running on different servers.

Thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: As of November 28 2016 this functionality is available. See this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334311-support-oauth-2-0-implict-flow

Answer (score 7):

Officially it's not supported by Microsoft, but with some modifications of experimental branch on github [azure-activedirectory-library-for-js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) you can get it working.

Fix logout url to v2.0 endpoint of oauth2 protocol with the policy parameter in the logOut method of adal.js at line 546:

```
var urlNavigate = this.instance + tenant + '/oauth2/v2.0/logout?' + logout + (this.config.extraQueryParameter ? '&' + this.config.extraQueryParameter : '');
```

The username property is never set in method _createUser of adal.js. The username is used in renew token process, fix it by adding this three lines:

```
if (parsedJson.hasOwnProperty('emails')) {
    user.userName = parsedJson.emails[0];
}
```

Finally, in adal-angular.js at line 146, acquireTokenSilent is called with wrong type parameter. This method accept only array type as scopes parameter, fix it by placing clientId in array:

```
_adal.acquireTokenSilent([_adal.config.clientId], null, function (error, tokenOut) {
```

I already pulled a request on [github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/pull/311/files) about this, you can use it as reference.

When you initialize adal provider on angular put your b2c sign in policy in extraQueryParameter like this:

```
adalProvider.init({
    tenant: 'tenant.onmicrosoft.com',
    clientId: 'clientid',
    extraQueryParameter: "p=B2C_1_SignIn"
}, $httpProvider);
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an AzureAD B2C scenario sample code for SPA was just released on github. See it [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi).

"The sample shows how to build a web application using Hello.js that performs identity management with Azure AD B2C.  The app is a simple web application that performs sign-in, sign-up, and sign-out functions with sign-in and signIn-signUp policies and also edit profile using EditProfile Policy."

NOTE: At the time of this answer the functionality is still in "preview"

Answer (score 2):

This is [not currently supported](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-limitations/).

> ## Single Page Applications (Javascript)
>
> Many modern applications have a Single Page Application (SPA)
> front-end written primarily in Javascript and often using a SPA
> frameworks such as AngularJS, Ember.js, Durandal, etc. This flow is
> not yet available in Azure AD B2C preview.