# Azure B2C Implicit Flow for SPA using Auth API gives invalid token for openid scope

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup my application to use Azure B2C's Implicit Flow token strategy to give me tokens via the post-signup/signin login in the URI. This works fine and the tokens authorize without a hitch.

However, the client is an SPA, so when the token expires, the documented workaround suggested by Microsoft is to use an iframe that makes a call to the `authorize` endpoint as documented here: [Get Access Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit#get-access-tokens)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={my_client_id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&scope=openid&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910&prompt=none&domain_hint=organizations&login_hint=myuser@mycompany.com
```

Unfortunately if I request an id_token using the openid scope with this endpoint, the token that's actually returned does not authorize via B2C in my API. Examining the JWT token in a decoder also shows that the token itself looks different than the one given post-signin from B2C.

I realize this documentation is for Azure Active Directory and that [B2C doesn't support SPAs at this point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#current-limitations), but I had heard from Microsoft representatives previously that this should work.

Is this really not supported yet? And if not, are there any workarounds for SPAs?

Comment: There is a similar post her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975012/authenticating-against-a-webapi-using-azure-b2c-from-an-spa-angular-and-adal-js/38035044#38035044

Comment: I've already seen that post. This question is not about ADAL, it's about the token endpoint. I'm not developing the SPA itself so have no control over it.

Comment: Can you give more details on how you secure your api?

Comment: As of November 28 2016 this functionality is available. See this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334311-support-oauth-2-0-implict-flow

Comment: @user1843640 see my comment below. It was on November 29, not 28.

Answer (score 2):

> Many modern apps have a single-page app front end written primarily in JavaScript. They often use a framework such as AngularJS, Ember.js, or Durandal. The generally available Azure AD service supports these apps by using the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow. However, this flow is not yet available in Azure AD B2C.

This feature is not support yet as the document stated at present. If you want  Azure AD B2C to support this feature, you can vote it from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334311-support-oauth-2-0-implict-flow).

Comment: Thanks, I was actually looking for where to vote for it. Added mine!

Comment: It looks like yesterday this request was completed! Great! But, I'm not exactly sure how to do the silent refresh from the client side...the only info about it is this one line: "Silent Renew the token before expiry t get the refresh token." Does that just mean to use the sign-in endpoint again?